# Calls fail when I try to make calls in Facetime

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, facetime

I was able to make calls with Facetime before. It is linked to my iPhone, and all the necessary settings are correct. I've given the iPHone a hard reboot, and I've restarted the Macbook Pro several times.

Comment: what happens exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the response, and sorry for the long delay. I hope you're still there!

I looked again. The problem apparently originates NOT in Facetime but with the phone. The "allow calls on other devices" setting will not stay turned on. In the last week, it did seem to stay on for a day, and I could make calls with Facetime. Then mysteriously it turned off, and it quickly turns itself off again every time I turn it on.

Comment: I would say that you should rewrite the title of this post and the post too, so that  it's more understandable, like in your comment - the setting "allow..." quickly turns off